# Can two access points in the same area "loop" each-other and then lose internet connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-connection, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration

need some help.
we have a 2 story house. The main router sits on the first floor, north side of the house near the window.
The first floor WIFI signal is ok, until a certain point. The second floor WIFI reception is pretty bad.

I bought 2 Access points. TP-Link TL-WA801ND, TP-Link TL-WA701ND.
The 701 for the first floor (southern part of the house, because most of the signal is ok, figured we didn't need a stronger one there), installed it in the middle of the house, and the 801 for the second floor. I've installed it near the stairs.

Reception is now great. all of the house has great WIFI signal and all is well 90% of the time.
Suddenly I began to notice that sometimes, the second floor access point has no internet connection. most of the time it works great, everything is groovy and we can play online and use everything 100%, but suddenly we get a message that(Windows PC) "there is no internet access on this wifi network", and this doesn't solve until I restart the second floor AP and sometimes even the main router.

did the 1st floor AP somehow "looped" with the second floor one? why there is not internet access all of a sudden?
before I bought the APs, this didn't happen.

thanks!

Comment: You might want to add a little more detail about how the APs are configured.   For example, are they wired into your main router or connected to the main router over wireless? What mode are the AP's setup in? I see on TP-Link's site that you can use: Access Point, Multi-SSID, Client, Universal/WDS Repeater, Bridge with AP, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably need a little more information to give a good answer (see my comment on your question), but here are a few things you could look into.

1. Are the access points wired to the router?  If you have the resources and ability to do that, it will always give you *much* better results than hooking up the access points in a repeater/range extender configuration.
2. Are the access points configured to pass DHCP requests to the main router?  If not and each access point is trying to use its own DHCP server then you may be seeing IP address conflicts causing clients to essentially lose connectivity.
3. Are all the devices (access points and main router) configured to use [non-overlapping channels?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels)  If not, you may see throughput problems as a result - but I'd doubt you'd see the "no internet access" message.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer.
I have done a hard reset to the Repeater and reconfigured it. seems like the default option was DHCP server enable. I've cancelled it and reconnected it. this actually seems like it was the problem.